# iOS7 - App causes device (not app) to crash

Tags: iphone, ios7

Our company has an app which is basically an eBook reader.

We use the [RMSDK](http://www.datalogics.com/products/rmsdk/) to perform book downloads & read.

Now, something very strange is happening in iOS7 devices (not in the simulator):

1. I download a book using the fulfillment method in the RMSDK
2. I wait for the book to finish downloading. The book is saved in the NSCachesDirectory (for App Store guidelines reasons) - so far, everything works fine
3. I hit the home button, the app moves to the background
4. I hit the app button to bring the app back, that's when the problem happens:

The app gets completely stuck. Hitting the home button does nothing, hitting the power button shuts down the screen, but then hitting the power button again does nothing.
The device itself has effectively crashed.

After a few minutes, the Apple logo appears on the device and the device comes back to life after a reboot.

I have no idea what in my code could be causing the device to act this way. Shouldn't the iOS7 sandbox prevent me from being able to crash the whole device?

Any ideas on why this could be happening and what I can do to prevent it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I placed a breakpoint on  the -(void)applicationDidBecomeAcvive: method in the AppDelegate, and it's not being called when clicking on the app icon in the last phase before the crash.

**EDIT:**
The RMSDK is using libcurl to download the books. Could this be a cause for this behavior?

**EDIT:** 
The problem is happening if I click on ***ANY*** app after I click on the home button, not just on the same app. So for example, I click on the home button, then I try to open *Fruit Ninja*, and the device crashes.

Comment: If your app crashes iOS, that's an iOS bug, without exception. The sandbox doesn't prevent OS-level bugs from causing crashes. File a bug and hope for the best.

Comment: We've already done that, but I was hoping to get some information on I might be doing to cause this on my side. We already have several major clients with this app, and waiting for a response from Apple just isn't good enough right now :/

Comment: Have you implement any thing regarding multitasking ?

Comment: There are, but I've already tried removing them to see if it makes any difference and it doesnt

Comment: Huge instantaneous memory consuption can make springboard restart, or freeze. Try to profile using memory allocation and vm tracker.

Comment: No huge allocations are visible via the profilers. Also, the applicationWillBecomeActive method isn't being invoked, so my code doesn't even have a chance to ruin something when the app becomes active again. Whatever I'm doing that causing the OS to react this way, it's happening once I finish downloading and triggers once the app returns to the foreground.

Comment: This question seems to have more information about this issue but not an obvious solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493959/ios-7-application-crashing-the-whole-ipad

Answer (score 1):

We managed to solve this issue by disabling functions in RMSDK, which call `mkfifo()`. I'm not sure how much I can say here due to NDA but they're all located in one file and can be cleanly converted to no-ops with a nice preprocessor `#if defined()`

Answer (score 0):

Its an OS level bug. iOS 7 is still unstable in areas, for example my Apps report crashes in places that are part of iOS 7 itself and couldn't be caused by my app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there's clearly something in my code that's causing the OS to react this way. While I understand that this stems from a problem in the OS, I'm looking for a quick fix in my code, or at least to understand what my code could possibly be doing to cause this sort of reaction from the OS.

Comment: It must be not reading it from the caches directory properly ? Does it crash when you reopen it again ?

Comment: No. Once the device restarts, all books that were previously downloaded exist and be accessed without a problem. The scenario occurs specifically after downloading.

Comment: It must be something to do with the app restoring its state. Is there any code to do with state restoration ?

Comment: no, nothing to do with state restoration. I can confirm that the applicationWillReturnToForeground method isn't even being called.