# iOS 7 Application Crashing the whole iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios7

I am getting a very strange crash while using an application in iOS7. It's basically an eReader application that I am working on and while opening a book, and putting iPad to sleep, the whole iPad crashes!!! It just doesn't crash, it freezes completely and the user will have to hard reset it by pressing and holding the home and lock button. If they don't, the iPad will restart in 5 minutes but for that period, the iPad is completely frozen.

I have spent numerous hours and checked to see if all the threads are clean, tried deleting all the application delegate methods like "applicationWillResignActive", "applicationDidEnterBackground" etc but no go!

I am adding the log of the console:

```
Oct 21 13:53:45 iPad backboardd[29] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
Oct 21 13:53:45 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 0 (set level to 0x37e)
Oct 21 13:53:45 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 0
Oct 21 13:53:45 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleMultitouchZ2SPI: updating power statistics
Oct 21 13:53:45 iPad backboardd[29] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255
Oct 21 13:53:45 iPad SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: [MPUNowPlayingController] Not registered for now playing notifications. Ignoring call to -unregisterForNotifications.
Oct 21 13:53:45 iPad profiled[177] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service starting...
Oct 21 13:53:46 iPad Lightsail[173] <Warning>: RTMPClient -> disconnect: *** DISCONNECT... *** <retainCount == 1
Oct 21 13:53:46 iPad Lightsail[173] <Warning>: --------------------------------------- doDisconnect
Oct 21 13:53:46 iPad Lightsail[173] <Warning>: applicationWillResignActive
Oct 21 13:53:46 iPad Lightsail[173] <Notice>: TestFlight: End of Session
Oct 21 13:53:49 iPad Lightsail[173] <Warning>: applicationDidEnterBackground
Oct 21 13:53:49 iPad Lightsail[173] <Warning>: App is up to date
Oct 21 13:53:49 iPad Lightsail[173] <Warning>: {(
        <UserSession: 0x177a7df0> (entity: UserSession; id: 0x1784d1d0 <x-coredata://2A1EBEB3-C354-4626-B699-7FEAA7C39D16/UserSession/p1> ; data: {
        actualSessionID = 51923;
        iD = "x-coredata:///UserSession/t12CF6E6E-C607-4B6B-9266-D53F0903E5199";
        identifier = nil;
        lastPing = "2013-10-21 11:53:42 +0000";
        serverID = 1;
        sessionEnd = "2013-10-21 11:53:49 +0000";
        sessionID = nil;
        sessionStart = "2013-10-21 11:52:17 +0000";
        userSessionType = 3;
        userSessionTypeID = 1308442;
    }),
        <UserSession: 0x17bb9e70> (entity: UserSession; id: 0x17bc5fb0 <x-coredata://2A1EBEB3-C354-4626-B699-7FEAA7C39D16/UserSession/p3> ; data: {
        actualSessionID = 284053;
        iD = "x-coredata:///UserSession/t12CF6E6E-C607-4B6B-9266-D53F0903E519285";
        identifier = nil;
        lastPing = "2013-10-21 11:53:42 +0000";
        serverID = 1;
        sessionEnd = "2013-10-21 11:53:49 +0000";
        sessionID = nil;
        sessionStart = "2013-10-21 11:53:34 +0000";
        userSessionType = 1;
        userSessionTypeID = 37025;
    }),
        <UserSession: 0x17dc5660> (entity: UserSession; id: 0x17dc5fd0 <x-coredata://2A1EBEB3-C354-4626-B699-7FEAA7C39D16/UserSession/p4> ; data: {
        actualSessionID = 33899;
        iD = "x-coredata:///UserSession/t12CF6E6E-C607-4B6B-9266-D53F0903E519286";
        identifier = nil;
        lastPing = "2013-10-21 11:53:49 +0000";
        serverID = 1;
        sessionEnd = "2013-10-21 11:53:49 +0000";
        sessionID = nil;
        sessionStart = "2013-10-21 11:53:34 +0000";
        userSessionType = 7;
        userSessionTypeID = 1308442;
    })
    )}
Oct 21 13:53:49 iPad Lightsail[173] <Warning>: ===== Server details retrieved =====
Oct 21 13:53:56 iPad profiled[177] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.
Oct 21 13:55:56 iPad UserEventAgent[14] <Error>: watchdog: com.apple.backboardd not responding; forcing a crash
Oct 21 13:55:56 iPad UserEventAgent[14] <Notice>: watchdog: can be disabled with the shell command: defaults write com.apple.mobilewatchdog WatchdogEnabled -bool no
Oct 21 13:55:56 iPad ReportCrash[178] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/stacks+backboardd-2013-10-21-135556.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Oct 21 13:55:56 iPad CLTM[14] <Error>: CLTM: No ALS Event
Oct 21 13:55:56 iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.backboardd[29]) <Notice>: (com.apple.backboardd) Exited: Killed: 9
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: virtual void IOMobileFramebuffer::swapping_client_will_stop(IOMobileFramebufferUserClient *), AppleMobileCLCD, client (0x0x96e1a600) going to wait on swap 
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 1
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 1 (set level to 0x6d0)
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: virtual void IOMobileFramebuffer::swapping_client_will_stop(IOMobileFramebufferUserClient *), AppleMobileCLCD, client (0x0x96e1a600) exiting wait on swap 
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: virtual void AppleRGBOUT::do_power_state_change(): fSoft: 0 fHard: 1 swapBusy: 0 pendingSwap: 0x0 fController: 0 -> 0
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Notice>: void __IOHIDPlugInLoadBundles(): Loaded 5 HID plugins
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Error>: IOHIDService compatibility thread running at priority 63 and schedule 2.
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 255->0 (deferring until bootloaded)
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: IOReturn AppleRGBOUT::set_display_device_gated(uint32_t), 1
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: virtual void AppleRGBOUT::do_power_state_change(): fSoft: 1 fHard: 1 swapBusy: 1 pendingSwap: 0x0 fController: 0 -> 1
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: bool AppleRGBOUT::power_up_hardware()
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: virtual void AppleRGBOUT::do_power_state_change(): fSoft: 0 fHard: 1 swapBusy: 0 pendingSwap: 0x9f357a00 fController: 1 -> 1
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: IOReturn IOMobileFramebufferUserClient::set_hotplug_notify(void *, void *) 0x32ef76d1 0x18264200
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: IOReturn IOMobileFramebufferUserClient::set_hotplug_notify(void *, void *) 0x96e1a600 0xa8464540 0x32ef76d1 0x18264200
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: virtual void AppleRGBOUT::do_power_state_change(): fSoft: 0 fHard: 1 swapBusy: 0 pendingSwap: 0x0 fController: 1 -> 0
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: bool AppleRGBOUT::power_down_hardware()
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: bool AppleRGBOUT::power_down_hardware(), clock down RGBOUT
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Notice>: ALS: open: legacy auto brightness plugin _plugInEnabled=true
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Notice>: HID: Display IOHIDDisplaySetProperty: LogLevel = 6
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Error>: Successfully opened the IOHIDSession
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Error>: HID Session async scheduling initiated.
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Error>: HID Session async root queue running at priority 63 and schedule 2.
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Error>: HID Session async scheduling complete.
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad SpringBoard[33] <Error>: hidd died. Reestablishing connection.
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad locationd[52] <Error>: hidd died. Reestablishing connection.
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad SpringBoard[33] <Error>: hidd died. Reestablishing connection.
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad UserEventAgent[14] <Error>: hidd died. Reestablishing connection.
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad aggregated[37] <Error>: hidd died. Reestablishing connection.
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->0
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad backboardd[179] <Warning>: Migration complete (if performed). (Elapsed time: 0.00 seconds)
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad imagent[56] <Warning>: [Warning] Unable to get entitlements for client task. Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (POSIX error -1 - Unknown error: -1)"
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad imagent[56] <Warning>: [Warning] Denying xpc connection, task does not have entitlement: com.apple.private.icfcallserver  (SpringBoard:33)
Oct 21 13:55:57 iPad imagent[56] <Warning>: [Warning] Denying xpc connection, task does not have entitlement: com.apple.private.icfcallserver  (SpringBoard:33)
Oct 21 13:55:58 iPad backboardd[179] <Warning>: -[BKSystemAppSentinel lock_bootstrap] Found running system app (com.apple.SpringBoard, pid 180). Attempting to stop it...
Oct 21 13:55:58 iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.SpringBoard) <Notice>: (com.apple.SpringBoard) Throttling respawn: Will start in 5 seconds
Oct 21 13:55:58 iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.lightsail.ereader[0x9a12][173]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.lightsail.ereader[0x9a12]) Exit timeout elapsed (1 seconds). Killing
Oct 21 13:55:58 iPad com.apple.debugserver-300.2[160] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [00a0/060b]: error: ::thread_suspend (2f03) err = (os/kern) object terminated (0x00000025)
Oct 21 13:55:58 iPad com.apple.debugserver-300.2[160] <Warning>: 2 +0.001156 sec [00a0/060b]: error: ::thread_suspend (3003) err = (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Oct 21 13:55:58 iPad com.apple.debugserver-300.2[160] <Warning>: 3 +0.000819 sec [00a0/060b]: error: ::task_info ( target_task = 0x1b0f, flavor = TASK_BASIC_INFO, task_info_out => 0x27d5b928, task_info_outCnt => 8 ) err = (os/kern) invalid argument (0x00000004)
Oct 21 13:55:58 iPad com.apple.debugserver-300.2[160] <Warning>: 4 +0.033603 sec [00a0/1207]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x3c69ec, 18446744069414585344 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Oct 21 13:55:58 iPad com.apple.debugserver-300.2[160] <Warning>: Exiting.
Oct 21 13:56:03 iPad backboardd[179] <Warning>: Telling the system app that it can start immediately
Oct 21 13:56:03 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Warning>: Loaded logger: SBAppInstallationLog
Oct 21 13:56:03 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Warning>: Loaded logger: SBIconLog
Oct 21 13:56:03 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Warning>: Loaded logger: SBWorkspaceLogging
Oct 21 13:56:03 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Warning>: *** error reading settings archive file: <SBRootSettings: /var/mobile/Documents/com.apple.springboard.settings/RootSettings.plist> 
Oct 21 13:56:03 iPad backboardd[179] <Warning>: -[BKSystemAppSentinel lock_notePresenceOfSystemApp:] Now monitoring "com.apple.SpringBoard"
Oct 21 13:56:04 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:200: string SBNonDefaultSystemAppTag is not a valid gestalt question
Oct 21 13:56:04 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:200: string hidden is not a valid gestalt question
Oct 21 13:56:04 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:837: front-facing-camera cannot generate notifications yet
Oct 21 13:56:04 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: ipad is static and will never generate a notification
Oct 21 13:56:04 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: any-telephony is static and will never generate a notification
Oct 21 13:56:04 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: stand-alone-contacts is static and will never generate a notification
Oct 21 13:56:04 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: still-camera is static and will never generate a notification
Oct 21 13:56:04 iPad profiled[185] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service starting...
Oct 21 13:56:04 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Warning>: lockdown says the device is: [Activated], state is 3
Oct 21 13:56:05 iPad misd[186] <Notice>: unable to read plist for gettingmax wireless hosts
Oct 21 13:56:05 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Warning>: BTM: attaching to BTServer
Oct 21 13:56:05 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Warning>: [Warning] Services all disappeared, removing all dependent devices
Oct 21 13:56:05 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Warning>: Using your own bundle identifier as an NSUserDefaults suite name does not make sense and will not work. Break on _NSUserDefaults_Log_Nonsensical_Suites to find this
Oct 21 13:56:05 iPad backboardd[179] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->5
Oct 21 13:56:06 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Warning>: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
Oct 21 13:56:06 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Error>: WiFi: Consulting "no-sdio-devices" property.
Oct 21 13:56:06 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Error>: WiFi: "no-sdio-devices" property not found.
Oct 21 13:56:06 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[188] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/4867203C-7B23-44F5-B161-398914C62FE5 (sandbox)
Oct 21 13:56:07 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Warning>: SMS Plugin initialized.
Oct 21 13:56:07 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Error>: WiFi: Consulting "no-sdio-devices" property.
Oct 21 13:56:07 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Error>: WiFi: "no-sdio-devices" property not found.
Oct 21 13:56:07 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Warning>: WiFi picker plugin initialized
Oct 21 13:56:07 iPad SpringBoard[183] <Notice>: 2013-10-21 13:56:07.137|183|0x16e8cdb0: Region monitoring not available or enabled. Trigger ignored!
Oct 21 13:56:09 iPad syncdefaultsd[189] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDAlwaysOnAccount: no account (null)
Oct 21 13:56:09 iPad syncdefaultsd[189] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDAccount: no account
Oct 21 13:56:09 iPad syncdefaultsd[189] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDPIMAccount: no account (null)
Oct 21 13:56:15 iPad backboardd[179] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
Oct 21 13:56:15 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 0 (set level to 0x37e)
Oct 21 13:56:15 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 0
Oct 21 13:56:15 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleMultitouchZ2SPI: updating power statistics
Oct 21 13:56:15 iPad backboardd[179] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 5->255
Oct 21 13:56:17 iPad profiled[185] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.
```

As you can see in the line: 
Oct 21 13:55:58 iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.lightsail.ereader[0x9a12][173]) : (UIKitApplication:com.lightsail.ereader[0x9a12]) Exit timeout elapsed (1 seconds). Killing

It says something about exit timeout. com.lightsail.ereader is the identifier of my application.

Comment: You're opening a book and putting the iPad to sleep? Could you explain that a bit further?

Comment: is this a retina iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. It was a C++ file trying to access the device partitions that crashed the iPad. I managed to fix the problem by deleting that code. If anyone else is facing the same problem then I recommend that they check the file operations in their code to isolate the problem.

Comment: can you publish more details, which file calls, etc

Comment: @NSFeaster we are having the same problem with the ARM SDK. Could you please point us which part of the code to look at? Thanks!

Comment: The file calls are very specific to the system that I am using. It's basically querying the system for the partitions after which, it will save some information into it.